# How can I get a total value from the same column of multiple rows in a mysql query?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a project in ASP.Net (C#) connected to a game database. I have a `player` table and I want to get the total value of the `playtime` row from all the players with the same `account_id`. My last logic was this:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
String queryStr;
String connStringPlayer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PlayerDB"].ToString();
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStringPlayer);
conn.Open();
queryStr = "SELECT playtime FROM player.player WHERE account_id='" + AccountId + "' LIMIT 5";
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
{
    Int32 countpt = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    String playcount = countpt.ToString();
    AccountInfoTotalGameMinuetsValue.Text = playcount;
}
conn.Close();
```

In this way my `AccountInfoTotalGameMinuetsValue` Label displays only the `playtime` of the 1st player of this `account_id` (2 players exist in this account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) is what you are looking for

> SUM([DISTINCT] expr)
>
> Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns
>   NULL. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to sum only the distinct values
>   of expr.
>
> SUM() returns NULL if there were no matching rows.

So the following query Will give you the totals for all the players

```
SELECT account_id, SUM(playtime) FROM player.player GROUP BY account_id;
```

if you want the information for just one player

```
SELECT account_id, SUM(playtime) FROM player.player 
WHERE account_id = some_id 
GROUP BY account_id;
```

Comment: Thanks I think it helped :)